# Cannot assign value of type '[String]?' to type 'String?'

Tags: swift

This is the var `var types: [String]?` and here i get this error  `myLabel3.text = place.types` how can i adjust it? I looked to other similar questions but not find something that is the same to my problem.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

private let geometryKey = "geometry"
private let locationKey = "location"
private let latitudeKey = "lat"
private let longitudeKey = "lng"
private let nameKey = "name"
private let openingHoursKey = "opening_hours"
private let openNowKey = "open_now"
private let vicinityKey = "vicinity"
private let typesKey = "types"
private let photosKey = "photos"


class QPlace: NSObject  {

    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var name: String?
    var photos: [QPhoto]?
    var vicinity: String?
    var isOpen: Bool?
    var types: [String]?

    init(placeInfo:[String: Any]) {
        // coordinates
        if let g = placeInfo[geometryKey] as? [String:Any] {
            if let l = g[locationKey] as? [String:Double] {
                if let lat = l[latitudeKey], let lng = l[longitudeKey] {
                    location = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
                }
            }
        }

        // name
        name = placeInfo[nameKey] as? String

        // opening hours
        if let oh = placeInfo[openingHoursKey] as? [String:Any] {
            if let on = oh[openNowKey] as? Bool {
                isOpen = on
            }
        }

        // vicinity
        vicinity = placeInfo[vicinityKey] as? String

        // types
        types = placeInfo[typesKey] as? [String]

        // photos
        photos = [QPhoto]()
        if let ps = placeInfo[photosKey] as? [[String:Any]] {
            for p in ps {
                photos?.append(QPhoto.init(photoInfo: p))
            }
        }
    }
```

this is place class and this is the func of my customTableViewCell where i want to add it

```
func update(place:QPlace) {
        myLabel.text = place.getDescription()
        myImage.image = nil
        myLabel2.text = place.vicinity
        myLabel3.text = place.types
```

Comment: You are adding string array to label property which takes string?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you intend to do more clearly. By your question i assume that types is an string array, but what is place.types is not clear.

Comment: Please read the error message carefully. `[String]` is a collection type (array) and `String` a single object. Swift’s strong type system doesn’t support this kind of mismatch. You have to flatten the array or select one particular item to assign

Comment: @Jeet i edited the question

Comment: As mentioned in the error, `types` is an array of strings, which you'd assign it to a string (`myLabel3.text`)! what are you aiming for?

Answer (score 1):

`var types: [String]?` is an optional array of `String`; the value of `myLabel3.text` is an optional `String`, or `String`?.

You need to get a value out from the array or join the values in order to set your label text, eg:

```
myLabel3.text = place.types?.joined()
```